# calling an akka actor from its outside is very slow

Tags: java, akka, akka-cluster

i'm new to akka. I made a ping-pong example between two actors (Ping Actor and Pong Actor) from two nodes on local machine and then test them in 2 different ways. Basically, Ping Actor will send a message is `System.nanoTime()` to Pong Actor. After get the message, Pong actor resend the received nano time back to Ping Actor.
Then I can calculate the taken time of a ping-pong round.

Way 1: main <-> pingActor <-> pongActor

> Main1:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        pingActor.tell("start", null);
    }
```

> PingActor:

```
public Receive createReceive() {
       return receiveBuilder()
            .matchEquals("start", start -> {
                pongActor.tel(System.nanoTime(), self());
            })
            .match(String.class, aboveTime -> {
                long timeDiff = System.nanoTime() - Long.parseLong(aboveTime);
                System.out.println(timeDiff);
            })
           .build();
}
```

Way 2: main -> pingActor <-> pongActor

> Main2:

```
    pingActor.tell("start", null);
```

> PingActor:

```
public Receive createReceive() {
       return receiveBuilder()
            .matchEquals("start", start -> {
                pongActor.tel(System.nanoTime(), self());
            })
            .match(String.class, aboveTime -> {
                long timeDiff = System.nanoTime() - Long.parseLong(aboveTime);
                System.out.println(timeDiff);
                pongActor.tel(time, self());
            })
           .build();
}
```

My test result shows that the 1st way is really slower (100ms average) than the 2nd way (1ms average). I need the explanation, and how to make a call from outside of an actor as fast as inside it does?
Thank you

Comment: I mean obviously you have one more call that goes into the second actor. So therefore it should be slower ? And honestly you need all the overhead of scheduling a call from the outside.

Comment: @jojo_Bẻlin  the time calculated was just about between pong actor and ping actor. đi not include the calling from main method.

Answer (score 0):

The compare between way1 & way2 is not fair.

**way1**

`Ping` actor will concurrently handle more than one message at same time, as the send speed of `Main1` is too quick, some message will queued in mailbox, this result in some response message from `Pong` also queued in `Ping`'s mailbox, so the differ here is not the real speed of message transfer.

You need to be aware that actor is run in one thread unless you increase `nr-of-instances`. Meanwhile, akka's actor model does not use coroutine, in the backend it still works on threadpool, so if the scenario is more complex, you may find more delay, so you need to carefully handle non-blocking for akka based application.

**way2**

From `way1`'s explanation, you could find your `way2` in fact is run in sequence mode, which the differ reflects the real transfer speed between actors, it does not include the buffer time in queue. So it quicker than `way1`. If your `Main2` also use a for loop, the speed will also drop; correspondingly, if you add some delay in for loop such as `Thread.sleep(1000)`, the `way1`'s differ will be smaller. However, I think your test data for `way2` still a little slower, on my local machine, the message transfer speed is 50,000+ per second.

For `how to make a call from outside of an actor as fast as inside it does?`
This is really a big question, what you do is just the way, but you may need to carefully design your actors to fully make use of underlying threadpool & also you need to know the running mechanism of akka's actors, then you can make akka powerful in your application.